# Temporal window $\{v(t)\}$ of Welch estimator

Tags: estimation, power-spectral-density

The Welch estimate [1] of PSD (power spectral density) is determined as:
$$\hat{\phi}_W(\omega)=\frac{1}{S}\sum_{j=1}^S \hat{\phi}_j(\omega)$$
where
$$\hat{\phi}_j(\omega)=\frac{1}{MP}\left|\sum_{t=1}^M v(t) y_j(t) e^{-i\omega t}\right|^2$$
is a 'windowed periodogram' corresponding to $y_j(t)$ and
$$P=\frac{1}{M} \sum_{t=1}^M |v(t)|^2$$
denotes the 'power' of the temporal window $\{v(t)\}$.

What is, for the Welch estimator, a common choice of temporal window $\{v(t)\}$?

[1] Welch, Peter D. "The use of fast Fourier transform for the estimation of power spectra: A method based on time averaging over short, modiﬁed periodograms." IEEE Transactions on audio and electroacoustics 15.2 (1967): 70-73.